# Stopping a Thread in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to stop a Thread in a Fragment. I have a Fragment and in that Fragment I have a Thread that check a method every 1 second.

I want, when user press button back on Device this Thread is stopped. To do it I'm trying use `onStop()`, `onPause()` and `onDestroyView()` and `onDetach()` of Fragment, but doesn't work. To works I need close my application totally.

I did read the document of Fragment about lifecycle, but still can't implement it.

How can I do it ?

```
        //thread
        Thread checkProgress = new Thread(){
                                        public void run(){
                                            while(!cpb.isDone()){
                                                if(cpb.isDone() && !click){
                                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                                                        
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void run() {                                                             
                                                            showDialog(1);                                              
                                                        }
                                                    }); 
                                                    isInterrupted();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }                                           
                                    };
                                    checkProgress.start();



        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            Log.i("ON DETACH: ", "execute");
            checkProgress.isInterrupted();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            Log.i("ON DESTROY VIEW: ", "execute");
            checkProgress.isInterrupted();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {         
            super.onPause();
            Log.i("ON PAUSE: ", "execute");
            checkProgress.isInterrupted();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            Log.i("ON STOP: ", "execute");
            checkProgress.isInterrupted();

        }
```

Comment: where is the code to stop the thread?

Comment: to close thread I'm simply set a boolean to true

Comment: How often does the thread check the boolean?

Comment: I edited the post with Thread

Comment: Does your log statement for on pause show up in logcat when you hit the back button?

Comment: does log only show if I close my application, or if I click in Dialog that opened in my Fragment. If I use button back of device (Samsung S4) doesn't log in LogCat.

Comment: I can't see any place where you are setting the exit *flag*

Comment: @Blackbelt I have `frameManager.addToBackStack("back")`. is it did you say ?

Comment: I'm solved the problem. In onStop() i added Thread.interrupt() and works.